# How many times have you reused your all-time most reusable component? (Yours)

Tags: design-patterns, oop

If you designed a toolkit, an application or a framework, mention the most reusable component you used of them,  how portable it is, how many times you reused it, how many programmers worked on it with you, and how much time did it take you to ship it. and also the names of the patterns you applied while developing it. (approximately of course).

**EDIT: To Clarify:** 
I'm talking about components you designed yourself. And please to try to use digits when mentioning the number of times you reused it.

Answer (score 1):

I have reused NUnit quite a few times since I wrote it. I gather that several other people have since used it also.

Answer (score 0):

1. Many times ? Project to Project.
2. Many times I used frameworks
   designed by others to save my time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Ruby class last summer that I have since used in perhaps 8 unique projects, including the original. I wrote it by myself. It has an hour or two into it all told.

Answer (score 0):

I have a generic Makefile which I use for pretty much all projects. It also has deployment options for tar-ing a website and scp-ing it to remote servers/staging servers. Makefiles, love-em, hate-em.